# How do I set the correct scope to call the Google People API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-api, google-people-api

I am trying to list directory people from my google account.

```
export class People {
  private auth: Auth.OAuth2Client;
  private initialized: boolean = false;
  private accessToken: string;

  constructor(private readonly clientEmail: string, private readonly pKey: string) {}

  public async people() {
    await this.initialize();
    const googlePeople = google.people({ version: 'v1', auth: this.auth });
    const people = await googlePeople.people.listDirectoryPeople();
    return people.data;
  }

  public async setToken(accessToken: string) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
  }

  private async initialize() {
    if (this.initialized) {
      return;
    }
    this.auth = new google.auth.OAuth2({
      clientId: 'xxx',
      clientSecret: 'zzz',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/people',
    });
    this.auth.setCredentials({
      access_token: this.accessToken,
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly',
    });

    this.initialized = true;
  }
}
```

However, the request fails with this error message:

```json
error: {
  code: 403,
  message: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  errors: [
    {
      message: "Insufficient Permission",
      domain: "global",
      reason: "insufficientPermissions"
    }
  ],
  status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

I did not find any info in Google docs on how to correctly set scopes for People API in JS. How to set the scope in this case?

Comment: I suspect that you changed the scope in your code, clear the cookies until it resets and requests for permissions again.

Comment: @DaImTo after clearing cookies and logging in again the issue persists :(

Comment: go to https://myaccount.google.com/permissions with the same user and remove the applications access, the hard way :)

Comment: How are you getting the auth url i dont see generateAuthUrl

Comment: @DaImTo removing permissions the hard way for my account will not work since this app will be used by more people and not everyone will be able to do that. As for generateAuthUrl, since this is not the only google module in the app, I am using passport for acquiring access token thus it is hidden eslewhere. However, I can get data with no problem from `people.people.get({ resourceName: 'people/me', personFields: 'address,names' })`

Comment: Well if you changed the scope in your code, after you had already authorized the user with a different scope then your code wont work.  You need to remove the access currently granted and force your application to get a new access token with the proper scope requested.   How you do that is up to you.

Comment: People.get has a different set of scope options then people.listDirectoryPeople.  Just because you have a key that will unlock the door to your own home does not mean that key will unlock the door to my home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

Means that the currently authenticated user, the user you logged in with to create the access token.  Has not granted you enough permissions to run the reuqest you are trying to run.

You appear to be trying to run the [people.listDirectoryPeople](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople) method which according to the documentation requires the following scope

[image]

As your appears to contain the following scope.

> scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly',

The access token you are currently using was not created with that scope, you need to run your application again and force it to request access of the user again and request that scope.

Either reset the cookies, or have the user forcefully remove the applications access via [Permissions](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) on their google developer account.  How you do this will be up to you.  But you need a new access token with the proper scope to use that method.

## people.get me works

[People.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) works because it uses different set of scopes any off the following will work.

[image]

But which means you could be using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` and `people.get` will work but `people.listDirectoryPeople` will not work because you do not have sufficient permissions, you need `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly`.

Comment: I have added this scope to the google strategy as well, cleared the cookies and re-logged in but it still does not work: 
```{ clientID: 'xxx', clientSecret: 'zzz', callbackURL: `${process.env.CLIENT_ORIGIN}/auth/callback`, scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly' }```

Comment: Removing access from `https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/permissions` did not help as well.

Comment: Found the issue. I was resetting my scopes in `passport.authenticate` method call. After updating its parameters it started working. Thank you!